# How to get the source code for Sample demo app that are available in Android AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator

For learning purpose I need to get the source code of the demo app "Finger Paint" that is available in Android AVD under Sample-Graphics. I want to get the complete project so that I can run the project in Eclipse and understand the working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full project is [here](https://github.com/nikt/Finger-Paint). You may also check [Link1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java) and [Link2](http://code.google.com/p/flatnote/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androsz/flatnote/handwriting/FingerPaint.java?r=10).